# ReactiveCocoa: throttle never executes / not working

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I try to subscribe to a signal with throttle, but it never executes.

I have a UISearchController *(Attention: UISearchController from iOS8, not the older UISearchDisplayController, which works quiet better and has thousands of working tutorials and examples in the web)* and want to make API-Requests while the user is typing.
To let the traffic being low, i don't want to start API-Requests with each key the user is pressing, but when the user stops for a while, say 500 ms after the last keypress.

Since we're unable to reference the TextField in the SearchBar of the UISearchController, we use the delegates from UISearchController:

To get the latest typed text of the Textfield in the Searchbar, I use this:

```
#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;

    // strip out all the leading and trailing spaces
    NSString *strippedString = [searchText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    if([strippedString isEqualToString:self.currentFilter]) {
        return;
    }
    self.currentFilter = strippedString;
}
```

The property *currentFilter* keeps the current search string.

Also, i have a RACObserve on the *currentFilter*-Property to react on every change which is made to this property:

```
[RACObserve(self, currentFilter) subscribeNext:^(NSString* x) {
    NSLog(@"Current Filter: %@", x);
    // do api calls and everything else
}];
```

Now i want to throttle this signal. But when i implement the call to throttle, nothing happens. SubscribeNext will never be called:

```
[[RACObserve(self, currentFilter) throttle:500] subscribeNext:^(NSString* x) {
    NSLog(@"%@", x); // will never be called
}];
```

How to achieve to throttle inputs in a searchbar? And what is wrong here?

**UPDATE**

i found a [workaround besides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29760716/1397160) ReactiveCocoa thanks to @malcomhall. I moved the code within the updateSearchResultsForSearchController-delegate method into a separate method and schedule it with performSelector and cancel this scheduler with cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget.

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(useTextSearchQuery) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(useTextSearchQuery) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

}
```

Anyway, i want still understand how "throttle" from ReactiveCocoa is working and why not in this case :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-throttle:` accepts an `NSTimeInterval`, which is a floating-point specification of *seconds*, not milliseconds.

Given the code in the question, I expect you would see results after 500 seconds have elapsed.