# Autocomplete UITextField Async update UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, asynchronous

I have a problem updating my tableView. So, I know how to implement autocomplete textfield with tableView. The problem is that my keyboard typing is not as smooth as I want it to be. Flow goes like this: when I type 3 characters, my async server method is called. It's response object returns my searched addresses. But the problem is that when I type, for like half a second, I cannot do anything, I need to wait until it loads result. I was wondering to solve it with `dispatch_group_t` but I need to enter and leave that async and then in notify method actually update my UI. This is the code:

```
if (string.length == 0 && range.length > 0) {
        if (newText.length >= 3) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [Address getAddreses:newText city:[City getDefaultCity] location:self.lockedPosition block:^(NSError *error, NSArray *addresses) {
                    self.suggestedAddresses = addresses;
                    if (addresses.count < AUTOCOMPLETE_RESULTS_MAX) {
                        self.sugesstedAddressesMaxResult = self.suggestedAddresses;
                    }
                    else {
                        self.sugesstedAddressesMaxResult = [addresses subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, AUTOCOMPLETE_RESULTS_MAX)];
                    }
                    [self calculateTableViewFrame:self.manualLocationInput tableViewTag:TAG];
                    [self.myTableView reloadData];
                }];
            });

        }
}
```

What I want to do: type as fast as I can, not to wait on every character half a second to update my UI. Typing should be like typing in messages, but it needs to update my table view according to latest typing.

Comment: You can use AFNetworking framework

Comment: I am using AFNetworking framework for my async call method using AFHTTPSessionManager

Answer (score 0):

If you clearly observe your code to fetch results of web service are happening in `displath_main-queue`. This is why you are facing issues while typing keyboard. Move `dispatch_get_main_queue` block to next level as shown below. This should your problem.

```
     //dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
     dispatch_queue_t globalConcurrentQueue =
     dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    dispatch_async(globalConcurrentQueue, ^{

    if (string.length == 0 && range.length > 0) {
    if (newText.length >= 3) {
            [Address getAddreses:newText city:[City getDefaultCity] location:self.lockedPosition block:^(NSError *error, NSArray *addresses) {
                self.suggestedAddresses = addresses;
                if (addresses.count < AUTOCOMPLETE_RESULTS_MAX) {
                    self.sugesstedAddressesMaxResult = self.suggestedAddresses;
                }
                else {
                    self.sugesstedAddressesMaxResult = [addresses subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, AUTOCOMPLETE_RESULTS_MAX)];
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self calculateTableViewFrame:self.manualLocationInput tableViewTag:TAG];
                [self.myTableView reloadData];
            }];
        });

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still facing the same problem. If I type next character in that half second, that new character is not recognised.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Even apple uses the same for getting autocomplete search for locations. Lets try.

Comment: I forgot to add that I am doing this in textfield's shouldChangeCharactersInRange:

Comment: Where ever you call service is not a matter unless you are running that in GCD queue. As others said check with AFNetworking once.

Answer (score 0):

whenever u type 3 or more char , getAddreses method call , which is perform on main thread . so it block main thread until it's not complete. i.e. until ur data reload ur ui not respond.

try: fetch data on back ground thread and just reload table on main thread.

Let me know if this works...

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer here: cancellation blocks

[How to throttle search (based on typing speed) in iOS UISearchBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330056/how-to-throttle-search-based-on-typing-speed-in-ios-uisearchbar)

Thank you all very much

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the *typical* solution in that case is to let the user types fluently until he stops typing. Then you can make a request in background and as soon as you receive the response, just update your **textfield** in the main thread.

In that direction you can just focus in your business logic, and to use a library like [SearchTextField](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField) for the suggestion list UI.