# Selector with completion, 2 variables and time interval

Tags: swift, swift3, performselector

Continuing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444310/live-search-throttle-in-swift-3/)

I have this function

```
func getSearch(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete, searchString: String) {

        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "action" : "search",
            "subaction" : "get",
            "product_name"  : searchString,
            "limit" : "0,30"
        ]
        Alamofire.request(baseurl, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let result = responseData.result

                if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                    if let list = dict["products_in_category"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                        if self.filteredData.isEmpty == false {
                            self.filteredData.removeAll()
                        }
                        for obj in list {
                            let manPerfumes = Products(productDict: obj)
                            self.filteredData.append(manPerfumes)
                        }
                    }
                }
                completed()
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see it handles one completion and one search string.

What i'm trying to do is this

```
extension SearchViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        
        if (searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count)! >= 3 {
                searchString = searchController.searchBar.text!
            NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(self.getSearch(completed:searchString:)), object: nil)
            
            perform(#selector(self.getSearch(completed:searchString:)), with object1: <How to add completion here?>, with object2: searchString, afterDelay: 0.5)    
        } else {
            self.searchResultTable.reloadData()
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

In this line

```
perform(#selector(self.getSearch(completed:searchString:)), with object1: <How to add completion here?>, with object2: searchString, afterDelay: 0.5)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add the completion on the first object and why i cant have 2 object and afterDelay??

Is it possible for me to have those 2?
And if yes, how can i extend the Perform class?

Comment: Use `DispatchQueue asyncAfter` instead of `perform...`

Comment: @rmaddy it should be the same i guess as the perform. right?

Comment: @rmaddy as i test it yes it does wait the time that i've told it to wait. Although is it a good practise to do so with asyncAfter?

Comment: Using `DispatchQueue` is much easier, cleaner, and safer than using `perform`.

Comment: Ok as i told you i tried it and it works smoothly without any memory issue!

Comment: But you then asked me if it is good practice. So I answered that question. Yes it is.